# Adding lines to a contour plot in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been tasked with adding lines to a contour plot in python. I am using the matplotlib in Python, but have only been able to get the contour plot. I need to add a bunch of small line segments where the coordinates are entries in a list of lists. I have tried adding an arbitrary line just to see how to do it but have failed with that. Here is my attempt.

```
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z = rfp(X, Y)
    plt.contour(X, Y, Z, 20, colors ='black')
    plt.plot([0.,0.], [1.,1.], '-k')
    plt.show()
```

However all this  code gives me is the contour plot. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What you have shown should work. However, there could be a few problems such as the `zorder` of the line or the line not lying within the axis limits

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve)

Comment: The reason, why you don't see anything, is that you plot a line from point (0,1) to point(0,1). It is just a point. The first parameter is a list of x-values, the second y-values. Please read [the matplotlib tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-pyplot-py). If you want to provide a list of xy points, you should, well, provide a list like `[[0.,0.], [1.,1.]]`.